# How to handle two signals at one time using struct sigaction and struct itimerval?

Tags: c, linux, function, signals

I'm trying to handle two signals at a time why is that not possible?

in this code only one sinal is firing, what ism the problem with the code?

```
//signal handler
void fun(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo,void *ptr)
{
    printf("si_code=%d\n",siginfo->si_code);
    printf("siGNO1=%d\n",siginfo->si_signo);
    printf("incoming\n");
    }
    void fun2(int sig,siginfo_t *siginfo,void *ptr)
    {
    printf("si_fd=%d\n",siginfo->si_fd);
    printf("signal2\n");
    }
    int main()
    {
    struct sigaction sig;  //sigaction
    sig.sa_sigaction=fun;
    sig.sa_flags=SA_SIGINFO;
    alarm(1);
    sigaction(SIGALRM,&sig,NULL);
    struct itimerval tim;
    struct sigaction sig2;
    memset(&sig2,0,sizeof(sig2));
    sig2.sa_sigaction=fun2;
    sig2.sa_flags=SA_SIGINFO;
    tim.it_value.tv_sec=1;
    tim.it_interval.tv_sec=1;
    tim.it_value.tv_usec=1;
    tim.it_interval.tv_usec=2;
    sigaction(SIGALRM,&sig2,NULL);
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL,&tim,NULL);
    while(1)
    {
    sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Again: Each signal has at most one handler per process. The second `sigaction()` does not set an "additional" signal handler for SIGALRM; it simply sets *the* signal handler for SIGALRM.

Comment: can u help me with this code?

Comment: Note that `printf()` is not an async-signal-safe function and can not be safely used in a signal handler.

Comment: incoming
incoming
incoming
incoming
signal2
signal2
signal2
                                                                                               /////////The output is like this,how can i trigger both alarms and execute fun()?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get two dispositions for same signal using sigaction. When kernel receive second [sigaction()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) request it simply replaces first disposition with the second one. However, if your intention is to handle a scenario where h1() executes when program receives SIGALRM and, H2() handler executes when timer expires then it can certainly be handled using [timer_create()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html).

[see this example as reference](https://github.com/aditya723/system-programming/blob/master/timer_and_sigaction.c)

Idea is:

1. Install SIGALRM handler using sigaction().
2. Create a timer using [timer_create()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) and [setitimer()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html). Use SIGEV_THREAD as notification for timer expiry.

> SIGEV_THREAD
>
> ```
>           Upon timer expiration, invoke sigev_notify_function as if it
>           were the start function of a new thread.  See sigevent(7) for
>           details.
> ```

3. Now when [alarm()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) will expire then SIGALRM handler will be executed and upon timer expiration  sigev_notify_function will be executed.

Always use [async-signal-safe functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) in signal hander context.

Comment: tq 
Vadim Kotov :)